# WPF Listview : Column reorder event?

Tags: wpf, listview

I need to sync the column order of two ListViews event when the user changes the order. But it seems there is not a Column reorder event.

For the moment I just did a AllowsColumnReorder="False" but that is not a permanent solution.  While searching the net I found many people with the same problem but no solution. What can be done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure it works, but you could probably take advantage of the fact that `GridView.Columns` is an `ObservableCollection` : you could subscribe to the `CollectionChanged` event and handle the case where `Action` = `Move`

```
GridView gridView = (GridView)listView.View;
gridView.Columns.CollectionChanged += gridView_CollectionChanged;

private void gridView_CollectionChanged(object sender, CollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move)
    {
        string msg = string.Format("Column moved from position {0} to position {1}", e.OldIndex, e.NewIndex);
        MessageBox.Show(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine so far. The syntax changed a bit. Use NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs, e.OldStartingIndex and e.NewStartingIndex

Comment: @TalkingCode Thank you! This change was necessary to use this code in .NET4.